# Why did Eliyahu go to the outskirts of Bes El but right into Y'richo?

Tags: travel, melachim-kings-book-of, eliyahu-hanavi, cities, elisha

In Ⅱ *M'lachim*, chapter 2, *Eliyahu* is about to be carried off to heaven, and his student, *Elisha*, knows it. Verses 2–5, with emphasis supplied:

> וַיֹּאמֶר אֵלִיָּהוּ אֶל אֱלִישָׁע שֵׁב נָא פֹה כִּי ה׳ שְׁלָחַנִי **עַד בֵּית אֵל** וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלִישָׁע חַי ה׳ וְחֵי נַפְשְׁךָ אִם אֶעֶזְבֶךָּ **וַיֵּרְדוּ** בֵּית אֵל.‏
>
> *Eliyahu* told *Elisha*: "Stay here, please, for God has sent me **as far as** *Bes El*." *Elisha* replied: "By the life of God and by your life, lest I leave you." They **went down to** *Bes El*.
>
> **וַיֵּצְאוּ** בְנֵי הַנְּבִיאִים אֲשֶׁר בֵּית אֵל אֶל אֱלִישָׁע וַיֹּאמְרוּ אֵלָיו הֲיָדַעְתָּ כִּי הַיּוֹם ה׳ לֹקֵחַ אֶת אֲדֹנֶיךָ מֵעַל רֹאשֶׁךָ וַיֹּאמֶר גַּם אֲנִי יָדַעְתִּי הֶחֱשׁוּ.‏
>
> The prophecy interns in *Bes El* **came out to** *Elisha*. "Did you know God's taking your master from over your head today?" they asked him. He said: "I knew that, too. Be quiet."
>
> וַיֹּאמֶר לוֹ אֵלִיָּהוּ אֱלִישָׁע שֵׁב נָא פֹה כִּי ה׳ שְׁלָחַנִי **יְרִיחוֹ** וַיֹּאמֶר חַי ה׳ וְחֵי נַפְשְׁךָ אִם אֶעֶזְבֶךָּ **וַיָּבֹאוּ** יְרִיחוֹ.‏
>
> *Eliyahu* told him: "*Elisha*, stay here, please, for God has sent me **to** *Y'richo*." *Elisha* replied: "By the life of God and by your life, lest I leave you." They **went in to** *Y'richo*.
>
> **וַיִּגְּשׁוּ** בְנֵי הַנְּבִיאִים אֲשֶׁר בִּירִיחוֹ אֶל אֱלִישָׁע וַיֹּאמְרוּ אֵלָיו הֲיָדַעְתָּ כִּי הַיּוֹם ה׳ לֹקֵחַ אֶת אֲדֹנֶיךָ מֵעַל רֹאשֶׁךָ וַיֹּאמֶר גַּם אֲנִי יָדַעְתִּי הֶחֱשׁוּ.‏
>
> The prophecy interns in *Y'richo* **approached** *Elisha*. "Did you know God's taking your master from over your head today?" they asked him. He said: "I knew that, too. Be quiet."

It seems that *Eliyahu* went to the outskirts of *Bes El* (so the interns had to come out), but into the city of *Y'richo*. Why the difference in destination?

Comment: Another question on the same verses: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Malbim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim) on this wording (verse 2) [explains](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39984&pgnum=148) that Elijah did not want to enter Beth-el, because one of Jeroboam's calf statues was there (Kings I [12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et09a12.htm):28-29).